# How to get eslint to comply with babel rules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, eslint

I have a simple babel config transpiling latest ES code into target which is `12.x` but when I try use the latest ES features such as optional chaining, eslint doesn't like it.

My babel config is like so:

```
{
  "sourceMaps": "inline",
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "^@/(.+)": "./src/\\1"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

and an eslint config like so:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'plugin:jest/recommended',
    'plugin:jest/style',
    'plugin:cypress/recommended',
    'eslint-config-prettier',
  ],
  env: {
    node: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true,
    browser: true,
  },
  plugins: ['no-autofix', 'jest', 'cypress'],
  rules: {
    ...
  },
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaVersion: 2019,
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  }
};
```

How can I tell eslint that ES version is actually not node v12.x but the 'latest'?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to update `parserOptions.ecmaVersion` to be `2021`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ESLint 8 (and you should), in your ESLint config, replace `es6: true` with `es2021: true` and remove `ecmaVersion: 2019`. According to [the documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments) this

> adds all ECMAScript 2021 globals and automatically sets the
> `ecmaVersion` parser option to 12.

If you really want to parse the latest language version rather than ES2021, then in the `parserOptions` you could set `ecmaVersion: "latest"`.